# Create a Web Service in CRM 2011

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

how can i create a web service in CRM 2011?
I know that organizationData.svc WS shows all entity but i want to create one new WS that show only one entity, how can i create it? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't create Web Services in CRM 2011. You have to use the CRM Web Services that is mantain by the system. When you add or change a new entity the system will update the Web Services. You can create a Web Service on top of CRM Web Services, but this is a common WCF service. Check here how you can connect with [CRM 2011](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334689.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: You can't make an addition to the CRM and just apply your own web service. You're left with three options here.

1. Forget about it and live with it.
2. Design an external web service that mimics such behavior.
3. Approach your task from a totally different angle.

(1) Lacks ambition so I wouldn't recommend it at all.

(2) Seems unnecessary to me. You can't stop the original service from serving the information anyway and the stuff you want to expose are included in it already.

(3) I know nothing of the task at hand but my guess is that whatever you wish to achieve, can be done by a different approach and redesign of the solution.